# JS replace() Using Regular Expression

Tags: javascript

I'm using JS to replace  `__[Text]__` with `<strong>[Text]</strong>`

Here is the code to be exact:

```
content.replace(/\__(.\*?)__/, "<strong>$1</strong>");
```

The content variable has `"Our __world__ is a vast and diverse place, filled with incredible wonders and complexities."` attached to it

It’s not replacing and I don’t know why.

BTW, I'm making a sorts of a Markdown converter.

Comment: `replace()` doesn't modify in place, it returns the new value. Did you assign the result somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape `_` and shouldn't escape `*` in `.*?`. Also remember to use the `g` flag to replace all occurrences.

```js
const content = "Our __world__ is a vast and diverse place, filled with incredible wonders and complexities.";
const res = content.replace(/__(.*?)__/g, "<strong>$1</strong>");
// note that the value of content has not changed
// only res holds the new value
console.log(res);
```

Comment: This didn’t work :( It’s not replacing

Comment: @INA Does the code snippet in my answer not work?

Comment: it does, but isn’t working when I copy it over.

Comment: @INA Can you show how you are using it in your code?

Comment: Wait! I got it to work I had a JS typo.